# move_uploaded_file does not work for files saved in seesion without showing any error messages

Tags: php, opencart

I am developing a site which allows users to upload images to their account. And the users are allowed to fill a form and upload images as a guest, and then be asked to login if they have not logged in yet, and then the files will be saved and update the database afterwards.

I am using opencart by the way,

The controller function to handle the form is

```
            if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
                //let's start the session
                if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                    session_start();
                }

                $this->session->data['partner_front'] = $this->request->post;
                $this->session->data['files'] = $this->request->files;
                $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('charity/partner&path=' . $project_id, '', 'SSL');
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
            } else {
                if(!isset($this->request->get['product_id'])){
                    $this->model_account_customerpartner->addProduct($this->request->post);
                    $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
                } else {
                    $this->model_account_customerpartner->editProduct($this->request->post);
                    $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success_update');
                }
```

The controller function in login part is

```
        if (isset($this->session->data['partner_front']) && $this->session->data['partner_front']) {
            $this->load->model('account/customerpartner');
            $this->model_account_customerpartner->addProduct($this->session->data['partner_front']);
            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            unset($this->session->data['partner_front']);
            unset($this->session->data['files']);
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/customerpartner/productlist', '', 'SSL'));
        }
```

And my model function which used to upload images and create temp name for the SQL is

```
public function addProduct($data){
$renamedImage = '';
$renamedOImage = array();
if(isset($this->session->data['files']) && $this->session->data['files']) {
    $files = $this->session->data['files'];
} else {
    $files = $this->request->files;
} print_r($files);

if (isset($files['image']['name']) AND $files['image']['name']) {
    if(count($files['image']['name']) == 1) {
        $renamedImage = rand(100000,999999) . basename(preg_replace('~[^\w\./\\\\]+~', '', $files['image']["name"][0]));
        move_uploaded_file($files["image"]["tmp_name"][0], DIR_IMAGE . MPIMAGEFOLDER .$renamedImage);
    } else {
        /**
         * upload product base image
         */
        $renamedImage = rand(100000,999999) . basename(preg_replace('~[^\w\./\\\\]+~', '', $files['image']["name"][0]));
        move_uploaded_file($files["image"]["tmp_name"][0], DIR_IMAGE . MPIMAGEFOLDER .$renamedImage);
        $renamedOImage[0] = $renamedImage;

        foreach (array_slice($files['image']['name'], 1) as $index => $product_image) {             

            $renamedImg = rand(100000,999999) . basename(preg_replace('~[^\w\./\\\\]+~', '', $product_image));
            //upload product images
            move_uploaded_file(array_slice($files['image']["tmp_name"], 1)[$index], DIR_IMAGE . MPIMAGEFOLDER .$renamedImg);

            $renamedOImage[$index] = $renamedImg;
        }

     }
}}
```

Right now, the image can be uploaded without going through the login controller function, but cannot be uploaded if the users are asked to login after submit the form.
I used `print_r($files)` to check the structure and content of the files before move_uploaded_file function, and get the same results of both of them.

Could anyone tells me why? Thanks a lot for any helps.

Comment: The uploaded file is only temporary, it's deleted when the script you upload to exits. You can't call `move_uploaded_file` in a later script in the session.

Comment: What @Barmar said^^^ But you could rename the temporary file in the `\tmp` folder and then it would not get auto deleted when the upload script exits. BUT you would have to remove it yourself in the second script and copy it some other way and remember its new name

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `move_uploaded_file` in a different script, because the uploaded file is deleted when the first script exits.

What you need to do is have the first script move the file to a permanent file, and put the filename in the session variable. Then the second script can link that file into the user's entry in the database after they login.

You might want to have a cron job that periodically deletes old files that haven't been linked to any accounts.

Comment: Do you mean the `move_uploaded_file` in the `else` part of the `addProduct()` function? But my problem happens when the `count($files['image']['name']) == 1` meets as well...And I was only testing uploading one picture at this moment, which caused problems like I said...

Comment: You need to do `move_uploaded_file` in the controller function that handles the form. The problem isn't in the session data, the problem is that the file you're trying to move no longer exists when the login controller runs.